# how to convert 2005-05-05 22:12 PM in to just dd/mm/yy

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, datetime

how to convert 2005-05-05 22:12 PM in to just dd/mm/yy
and why i am getting in the form of "/Date(1487548800000)/" while i am binding in view using angular js

```
public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            Entities contextObj = new Entities();

            var employeeList = contextObj.CCFFares.ToList();

            //return Json(employeeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

            return this.Json((from obj in contextObj.CCFFares

                              select new`enter code here`
                              {
                                  ID = obj.ID,

                              Departure_Airport = obj.Departure_Airport,
                              Destination = obj.Destination,
                              Departure_Date = obj.Departure_Date,
                              Return_Date = obj.Return_Date,
                              Airline = obj.Airline,
                              Fare = obj.Fare,
                              Offer_Ends = obj.Offer_Ends,
                              Ailine_Class = obj.Airline_Class
                          }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    GetData.then(function (fair) {

        $scope.fairs_destination = fairs.Destination;

        $scope.fairs_departure_date = $filter('date')(fairs.Departure_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy');

        $scope.fairs_return_date = fairs.Return_Date;

    }
```

I have wrote the C# code and the angular js function in the second method and finally i have represent the html angular js bind. can anyone please guide me on how to fix the date into plain dd/mm/yy format. and the date format is in DateTime format in sql getter setter access specifiers

```
<tr ng-repeat="fairs in fairs_deals | filter:query | orderBy:'ID'">
                                    <td>{{fairs.ID}}</td>
                                    <td>{{fairs.Departure_Airport}} </td>
                                    <td>{{fairs.Destination}}</td>
                                    <td>{{fairs.Departure_Date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{fairs.Return_Date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{fairs.Airline}}</td>
                                    <td>£{{fairs.Fare}}</td>
                                    <td>{{fairs.Offer_Ends}}</td>
                                    <td>{{fairs.Ailine_Class}}</td>
                                    <td>
```

Comment: Unclear what you're after. Just for a start, should we *truncate* to the 5th or should we *round* to the 6th? Also, unclear how the two parts of your question are related. If you have two questions, *ask* two questions. Don't cram them into one.

Comment: Please show some code related to the problem. You've tagged this as both C# and AngularJS without any explanation for how you got to this problem. There is currently no way to fit an answer into your code without your code.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the date format in controller or just want display in view in dd/mm/yy format ?

Answer (score 1):

Inject $filter in your controller and use this code to convert into any format:

```
$scope.formatted_datetime = $filter('date')($scope.variable_Containing_time,'dd/mm/yyyy');
```